# Maven link and compile external source not working

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

In my non-maven Java project, I can link an external source in eclipse and it compiles.

But when I link the same external folder to maven it does not compile, although I have declared the sourceDirectory for the linked source.

Following images will make my question clearer:

My maven workspace, on file system does not contain a folder named `java`

[image]

Through eclipse, I have linked a source folder:

[image]

And it appears in eclipse:

[image]

**Next**, I added `sourceDirectory` tag in my pom.xml for `java` directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <relativePath>../</relativePath>
    <groupId>com.mydomain</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-master</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </parent>  

  <artifactId>application</artifactId>  
  <name>application</name>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

   <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
  </properties>

   <build>
        <sourceDirectory>java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
              <excludes>                
                <exclude>**/old/**/*.java</exclude>                 
              </excludes>
              <includes>
                <include>com/**/*.java</include>
              </includes>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

But when I compile (either through command line or through eclipse), I get message

> No sources to compile.

[image]

Am I linking the folder in a wrong way?

Also, I am not sure if this info is needed or not, the main class is not at the root of `sourceDirectory` like `java/Main.java` but it's like `java/dir1/dir2/Main.java`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, for such cases `sourceDirectory` needs to have an absolute path to the source code location.

When I added absolute location (e.g. `D:\Project\<.....>\java`) ,  I was able to build through maven.